# Rails generate dynamic ffmpeg command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine several videos into one with `ffmpeg` command called from a Ruby script in a Rails `ActionJob` class. The number of input videos is unlimited. This is how I did it right now.

```
 def perform(project_id)
    @project = Project.find(project_id)
    logger.info 'ProjectGenerateVlogJob#perform'
    logger.debug "project: #{@project.inspect}"
    setup_directory

    result_filename = "#{@project.id}-vlog.mp4"
    execute_command = <<-FFMPEG
      find *.mp4 | sed 's:\ :\\\ :g'| sed 's/^/file /' > fl.txt; ffmpeg -f concat -i fl.txt -c copy #{result_filename}; rm fl.txt
    FFMPEG

    logger.debug "ffmpeg_command: #{execute_command}"
    `#{execute_command}`
  end
```

But that command is not stable, in a way that the generated video has problems, namely un-synch audio, video gets cut off, etc.

This is how I did it through the console manually that produced the best result so far:

```
$ ffmpeg -i IMG_1-same.MOV -i IMG_2-same.MOV -i IMG_3-same.MOV \
-filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] \
concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vsync vfr vlog-1.mp4
```

The thing is, I don't know how to generate the command dynamically so it can be run by the Ruby script. Any pointers?

The Project model has many videos, and when I looped through it it produced multiple lines of command and it's not a valid command when I run it from Ruby.

Comment: Instead of showing us some code that is very different from the command you're trying to create (and hence unsurprising that it creates a different output), you should show your attempt to create the command you DO want and explain the issues you're having with that effort.

Comment: _"I don't know how to generate the command dynamically"_ – you could use [`system`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) which allows you to pass the command line arguments separately. Populate an array like `args = ['-i', 'IMG_1-same.MOV', ...]` and then call it via `system('ffmpeg', *args)`